# Find rows of numpy array that are members of a set

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I want to find rows of a numpy array that are members of a set. For example:

`wanted=set([(1,2),(8,9)])`

`z=np.array([[1,2],[8,8],[2,3]])`

The result should be [1,2].

I could use a list comprehension:

`[b for b in z if tuple(b) in wanted]`

but this is slow when z has many rows and columns. Is there a faster way to do this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One vectorized approach would be to -

- Convert set `wanted` to a Numpy array with `map()` and `np.vstack`.
- Extend dimensions of Numpy array version of `wanted` with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to form a 3D array and compare against `z` bringing in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).
- Check for ALL True rows and ANY True first axis match, giving us a mask that could be used to index into `z` for final selection.

Implementation -

```
wanted_arr = np.vstack((map(np.array,wanted)))
out = z[((wanted_arr[:,None] == z).all(2)).any(0)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [64]: z
Out[64]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [8, 8],
       [2, 3]])

In [65]: wanted
Out[65]: {(1, 2), (8, 9)}

In [66]: wanted_arr = np.vstack((map(np.array,wanted)))

In [67]: wanted_arr
Out[67]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [8, 9]])

In [68]: z[((wanted_arr[:,None] == z).all(2)).any(0)]
Out[68]: array([[1, 2]])
```